Django retrieves old content from the database
I've developed an app using Django 5, tested it on my server and my local, and made it in production on my server. The problem is that when a certain action is taken to write or update a record in the database, it's not reflected in the frontend as if it's returning cached data. This only happens to the version in production on my server.
I tried the following:

Turned the debugging off.
Making sure the content was written to the database.
Clearing my local cache.
Trying to make CSS changes (It works!), but for database content, it doesn't work and no new data is shown.
Trying never cache for that view.
Checking if there is middleware caching.
Deleting pyc files.
Making a change to wsgi.py.
Restarting Apache several times.

Again, This never happens in my local it's just the server. I've also checked older questions, but nothing helps yet.
Note: I'm using Django 5, mySQL, Apache, and WSGI on AWS.
Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Does your app server actually receive the client's HTTP request and then query the DB and the DB returns cached content? What is not actually happening that should happen?

The request is sent and the database is always updated successfully. However, I see old data that no longer exist in the database whenever I render the view.
